# What is the difference between using "new RegExp" and using forward slash notation to create a regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, slash

Is there any difference between using `new RegExp("regex");` and `/same_regex/` to test against a target string? I am asking this question because I got different validating result while use these two approaches. Here is the snippet I used to validate an email field:

```
var email="didxga@gmail.comblah@foo.com";

var regex1 = new RegExp("^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$"); 

var regex2 = /^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$/;

//using RegExp object
if(regex1.test(email))  {
       console.log("email matched regex1");    
  } else {
       console.log("email mismatched regex1");   
  }
//using slash notation
if(regex2.test(email))  {
       console.log("email matched regex2");   
  } else {  
       console.log("email mismatched regex2");
  }
```

I got two inconsistent results:

```
email matched regex1
email mismatched regex2
```

I am wondering if there is any difference here or I omitted something in this specific example? 
For an executable example please refer to [here](http://jsbin.com/etugu5/2/edit)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you use the constructor to create a new *RegExp* object instead of the literal syntax, you need to escape the `\‍` properly:

```
new RegExp("^[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?$")
```

This is necessary as in JavaScript any unknown escape sequence `\x` is interpreted as `x`. So in this case the `\.` is interpreted as `.`.

Comment: In the slash notation ` \ ` and ` / ` out of char class definition must be escaped also.

Comment: @Philipp: Yes to `/` but no to the backslash.

Answer (score 13):

`/.../` is called a *regular expression literal*. `new RegExp` uses the RegExp constructor function and creates a Regular Expression Object.

From [Mozilla's developer pages](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions)

> Regular expression literals provide
>   compilation of the regular expression
>   when the script is evaluated. When the
>   regular expression will remain
>   constant, use this for better
>   performance.
>
> Using the constructor function
>   provides runtime compilation of the
>   regular expression. Use the
>   constructor function when you know the
>   regular expression pattern will be
>   changing, or you don't know the
>   pattern and are getting it from
>   another source, such as user input.

Answer (score 4):

this will be a help for you 
http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html
see the 'How to Use The JavaScript RegExp Object' section

if you are using RegExp(regx) regx should be in string format ex:-
\w+ can be created as `regx = /\w+/` or as `regx = new RegExp("\\w+")`.

Answer (score 2):

Difference is in escaping at least in your case.
When you use / / notation, you have to escape '/' with '\/', when you're using Regexp notation you escape quotes

Comment: ` / ` out of char class definition must be escaped also