# RegExp method "test" return wrong result

Tags: javascript, regex

Acoording to https://regex101.com/ regexp `'^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]$'` for strings like "g2", "a8" etc. (one digit preceded by one letter) should return "false" (no match), but if I use it in JavaScript using `RegExp` `test` method "true" is returned. What is the reason of that behaviour?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "g2";
    var patt = new RegExp('^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]$');
    var res = patt.test(str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Also, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769964/backslashes-regular-expression-javascript, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6521572/javascript-regex-not-working and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149770/what-is-the-difference-between-using-regexp-and-using-forward-slash-notation-to.

Comment: The takeaway here is: Wherever possible, use a regex *literal*: `var patt = /^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]$/;` When not possible, remember that backslashes have special meaning in string literals.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: What, only four? ;-)

Comment: You code should be like

`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction() {
    var str = "g2";
    var patt = new RegExp('/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]$/g');
    var res = patt.test(str);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = res;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>`

Comment: @SPViradiya: You have quotes there you don't want. But really, the linked questions' answers answer the question just fine.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I have changed the reguler expression. I did not saw you have suggested it already and just changed it with needed slash and slag "g".

Comment: @SPViradiya: Remove the quotes around the regex literal. But again, really best just to move on.

Comment: @SPViradiya: If you test your regexps at [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/Z41koT/1), you might have noticed the *code generator* option on the left. Click it, and you will see the code snippet you can leverage in your code.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Yes, just these four are enough. My favorite is [Backslashes - Regular Expression - Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10769964/backslashes-regular-expression-javascript).

Comment: Thank you for answers. Problem solved.

Comment: Yes @T.J. Crowder you are right. It should be  `var patt = new RegExp(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]$/g); ` And Yes @Wiktor Stribizew it shows it

Comment: @SPViradiya: *"It should be `var patt = new RegExp(/^[-+]?[0-9]*\.?[0-9]$/g);`"* OMG. No. See my very first comment above (immediately under Wiktor's "Also, see..." comment) for the correct syntax.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it works in this way too. You can check it buddy. :)

Comment: @SPViradiya: Yes, it *works*, it's just pointless. There's zero reason to wrap a valid regex literal in `new RegExp()` in 2016 (there was, briefly, a reason back in, oh, 2005) unless you're intentionally making a *copy*, and there's no need for that here.